# How can I change border style in a panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist that has a list of border style names like "Dotted,Solid,Groove..."
I need to change borderstyle , so tried something like this

```
Panel1.BorderStyle = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

this how i fill the dropdownlist
DropDownList3.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(BorderStyle));

But it doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. What actually happens. What should happen?

Comment: sry , border style should change to the selected

Comment: are you wanting to Change to `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem`

Comment: to selected item , transformed to string . for example i chose bold in dropdownpanel and after this it should change borderstyle of panel to bold

Comment: DropDownList3.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(BorderStyle)); this is how i fill the dropdownlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
string selectedStyle = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();

if (selectedStyle == "Dotted")
{
    Panel1.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Dotted;
}
else if (selectedStyle == "Solid")
{
    Panel1.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Solid;
}
// and so on ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you

```
 panel1.BorderStyle = (BorderStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(BorderStyle),
    DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

> You will need to add some additional code checks on your side just in case the BorderStyle is not found

Referenced from MSDN: [WebControl BorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.borderstyle.aspx)

Comment: This will not compile! `BorderStyle` is not of type `string` or `object`

Comment: Bala R this will compile now I updated my answer sorry the initial coding error..

Answer (score 1):

For me, I would have done something like:

```
panel1.BorderStyle = (BorderStyle)Enum.Parse ( typeof ( BorderStyle ), DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString () );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
```

Comment: This definitely does not answer the `OP's` question he's not looking to hard code a value

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it but maby you provide an Item collection with the real values like:

```
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Dotted
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Solid
 etc.
```

then try something like:

```
Panel1.BorderStyle = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
```